# Prev/next functionality failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Prev/next functionality not working on new section selection. The idea is that when the the page loads, several slide shows will load and the user will navigate through them with prev/next buttons. When they get to the end of one section, they will select the next section that they want to view. My problem is that the prev/next function doesn't work after the user navigates to a new section.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edubs/NmBSS/2/). So you don't miss them, the prev/next buttons are the edges of the prev/next slides hanging on the left and right side of the page, respectively. Below is the section of my javascript that I believe is causing the problem.

Thanks

```
var secName,
    slideCount,
    centSlide;

liveSec(0);

// Initiate live section
function liveSec(x) {
    centSlide = 0;
    secName = $('#slider > div:eq('+x+')').attr('id');
    slideCount = $('#'+secName+'').children().length;
    $('#'+secName+'').children().first().addClass('liveslide').next().addClass('next');
}

// call prev/next functions
$('#'+secName+' > div').click(function() {
    var index = $('#'+secName+' > div').index(this);
    if (index > centSlide) nextcycle(centSlide, slideCount);
    if (index < centSlide) prevcycle(centSlide, slideCount);
    return false;        
});

// cycle sections   
$('#'+secName+' .select').click(function () {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    $('.liveslide').removeClass('liveslide');
    $('.prev').removeClass('prev');
    i = $('#'+secName+' .select').index(this);
    liveSec(i);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not assign the function to the slides in other sections. Only the slides in first section have the onclick function defined. Make sure you loop through all of them at the beginning

```
for (var i=0; i < noOfSections; i++)
{
    var secName = sections[i];

   // call prev/next functions
  $('#'+secName+' > div').click(function() {
      var index = $('#'+secName+' > div').index(this);
      if (index > centSlide) nextcycle(centSlide, slideCount);
      if (index < centSlide) prevcycle(centSlide, slideCount);
      return false;        
  });

  // cycle sections   
  $('#'+secName+' .select').click(function () {
      if (!e) var e = window.event;
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
      $('.liveslide').removeClass('liveslide');
      $('.prev').removeClass('prev');
      i = $('#'+secName+' .select').index(this);
      liveSec(i);
  });
```

}

What actually worked for me in fiddle was when you move the closing bracket of the liveSec function underneath the second click function, but I'm not sure how your sections work, so it could end up assigning the click function multiple times unless you unbind it first.

```
// Initiate live section
function liveSec(x) 
{
centSlide = 0;
secName = $('#slider > div:eq('+x+')').attr('id');
slideCount = $('#'+secName+'').children().length;         
    $('#'+secName+'').children().first().addClass('liveslide').next().addClass('next');


   // call prev/next functions
$('#'+secName+' > div').click(function() {
    var index = $('#'+secName+' > div').index(this);
    if (index > centSlide) nextcycle(centSlide, slideCount);
    if (index < centSlide) prevcycle(centSlide, slideCount);
    return false;        
    });

    // cycle sections   
$('#'+secName+' .select').click(function () 
    {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
         e.cancelBubble = true;
         if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    $('.liveslide').removeClass('liveslide');
    $('.prev').removeClass('prev');
    i = $('#'+secName+' .select').index(this);
    liveSec(i);
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you Martina. It appears that moving the closing bracket is all I need to do.

Comment: As long as I only visit each section once, then this solution works. When I attempt to view a section for the second time, it fails. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think it must be because the click function gets assigned every time you go to the section, so second time you go to the same section the click events run twice. Try to assign them at the beginning, something like that for loop I made and then you don't have to worry about them any more.